# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable in odoo

Tags: python, orm, odoo, typeerror, odoo-8

all

I recieved error when add  data to table:

```
2016-06-22 12:14:59,292 21364 ERROR odoov8 openerp.addons.webvisitorcalc.controllers: prevouseURLsearchEngine: {'search_marker': u'q', 'id': 1, 'uniq_part_in_host': u'google'}
2016-06-22 12:14:59,292 21364 ERROR odoov8 openerp.addons.webvisitorcalc.controllers: search_engine_id: 1
2016-06-22 12:14:59,293 21364 ERROR odoov8 openerp.http: Exception during JSON request handling.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/skif/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 540, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/home/skif/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 577, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/home/skif/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 313, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/skif/odoo/openerp/service/model.py", line 118, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/skif/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 310, in checked_call
    return self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/skif/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 806, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/skif/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 406, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/skif/odoo/my-modules/webvisitorcalc/controllers.py", line 179, in register_session
    writeRelationSession.write({'search_engine_id':int(1)})
  File "/home/skif/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 266, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/skif/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 3788, in write
    self._write(old_vals)
  File "/home/skif/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 266, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/skif/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 592, in new_api
    result = method(self._model, cr, uid, self.ids, *args, **old_kwargs)
  File "/home/skif/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 3816, in _write
    for wtuple in vals[field]:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

How can I undestend this is relationship error. Other relation is working good.

My models file:
**[models.py]**

```
class SessionVisitor(models.Model):
        _name = 'webvisitorcalc.session_visitor'
        client_addr = fields.Char(string="Client IP", required=True)
        date_visit = fields.Datetime(default=fields.Datetime.now())
        date_last_check = fields.Datetime(default=fields.Datetime.now())

        target_url_ids = fields.Many2one('webvisitorcalc.url_list', string='Target URL')

        site_trip_id = fields.One2many('webvisitorcalc.site_trip', 'session_ids', string='Trip records')

        #search
        search_engine_id = fields.One2many('webvisitorcalc.search_engine', 'session_ids', string='Search engine')
        search_phrase_id = fields.One2many('webvisitorcalc.search_phrases', 'session_ids', string='Search phrase')

        # advert
        advert_company_id = fields.One2many('webvisitorcalc.advert_company', 'session_ids', string='Advert. company')
        advert_engine_id = fields.One2many('webvisitorcalc.advert_engine', 'session_ids', string='Advert. engine')


class SearchEngine(models.Model):
        _name = 'webvisitorcalc.search_engine'
        name = fields.Char(string="Engine name", required=True)
        uniq_part_in_host = fields.Char(string="Uniq part hostname", required=True)
        search_marker = fields.Char(string="marker for search phrase", required=True) # q='' для Google, text='' для Яндекс
        #utm_marker = fields.Char(string="UTM mark name", required=True)
        #url_list_ids = fields.Many2one('webvisitorcalc.url_list', string='Target URL')
        session_ids = fields.Many2one('webvisitorcalc.session_visitor', string='Session IDs')
```

This is code with error:
**[controllers.py]**

```
createParam = {}
if (prevouseURLsearchEngine!={}):
                _logger.error("prevouseURLsearchEngine: %r", prevouseURLsearchEngine)
                _logger.error("search_engine_id: %r", prevouseURLsearchEngine['id'])
                createParam['search_engine_id'] = int(prevouseURLsearchEngine['id'])
                writeRelationSession.write(createParam)
```

Can you suggest my error?

Comment: From the stack trace it looks like `vals[field]` is an int. What do you expect it to be?

Comment: This is field is: search_engine_id (class SessionVisitor). This is relation SessionVisitor<->SearchEngine. I write in this field id engine machine for visitor session who went from google or yandex.

Comment: Try this in the line of search_engine_id:


    createParam['search_engine_id' = [int(prevouseURLsearchEngine['id'])]

Comment: Now error is "TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '____getitem____' "

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would try:

```
createParam = {}
if prevouseURLsearchEngine:
    _logger.error("prevouseURLsearchEngine: %r", prevouseURLsearchEngine)
    _logger.error("search_engine_id: %r", prevouseURLsearchEngine['id'])
    # the search_engine field is a `OneToMany` so we are expecting an array not a scalar
    createParam['search_engine_id'] = [ int(prevouseURLsearchEngine['id']) ]
    writeRelationSession.write(createParam)
```

Comment: I recieved another error: *File "/home/skif/odoo/my-modules/webvisitorcalc/controllers.py", line 179, in __register_session
    writeRelationSession.write(createParam)__* and *File "/home/skif/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 3932, in _write
    result += self._columns[field].set(cr, self, id, field, vals[field], user, context=rel_context) or []
  File "/home/skif/odoo/openerp/osv/fields.py", line 796, in set
    if act[0] == 0:
__TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '____getitem____'__*

Comment: May be I have error in relation?
I want to write id from SearchEngine model to model SessionVisitor. For all record  SessionVisitor search_engine_id not uniq and this must be one numeric. Any records may have equal data.
I think in SearchEngine must be *session_ids = fields.Many2one('webvisitorcalc.session_visitor', string='Session IDs')* and in SessionVisitor must be *search_engine_id = fields.One2many('webvisitorcalc.search_engine', 'session_ids', string='Search engine')*. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for answers.
I wrote wrong relations. Relations in my classes must be change places.